# Wordpress Menu not showing

Tags: wordpress, menu, navigation

I'm using a theme called hotheme(dot co) which seems not working properly. I added some links to my menu in the backend and linked it to "main menu" but on the frontend the inspector shows an empty

Here's the code for the menu from the header.php

`

```
                global $wpdb;

                $tablename = $wpdb->prefix.'terms'; // use always table prefix

                // language support
                switch ($lang){
                    case '':
                    case '1':
                        $menu_name = 'default';
                        break;
                    case '2':
                        $menu_name = 'secondary';
                        break;
                }
                $menu_id = $wpdb->get_results(
                    "
                    SELECT term_id
                    FROM ".$tablename." 
                    WHERE name= '".$menu_name."'
                    "
                );

                // Empty check
                if($menu_id != null){

                    // results in array 
                    foreach($menu_id as $menu):
                        $menu_id =  $menu->term_id;
                    endforeach; 

                    $items = wp_get_nav_menu_items( $menu_id );
                    $numItems = count($items);
                    $i = 0;

                    foreach($items as $item)
                    {
                        if(++$i === $numItems) {
                            echo "<li class='reservation-btn custom-color-btn-back'><a href='".$item->url.$lang_link.$lang."'>".$item->title."<br /><span class='grey'>".$item->description."</span></a></li>";
                            $_SESSION['reservation_url'] = $item->url;
                        } else {
                        echo "<li><a href='".$item->url.$lang_link.$lang."'>".$item->title."<br /><span class='grey'>".$item->description."</span></a></li>";
                        }
                    }
                } // end: empty check 

                ?>`
```

Could it be possile, that the code is deprecated?

Any help would be great! Thanks

Comment: I can't think of any good reason why you'd need `$wpdb` to return a simple menu...

Comment: yeah the guys who made the theme decided that… 

Answer (score 0):

That seems like a lot of unneeded code. I am going to give you some code (alters slightly) that I wrote for a theme framework that I am working on. You can add it to the theme and see if a menu shows up or not.

Add to functions.php

```
function ao_register_menus() {
  register_nav_menu( 'primary', 'Primary Navigation');
}

add_action( 'init', 'ao_register_menus' );   

function ao_primary_nav() {
    echo '<nav class="primary-navigation">';
    wp_nav_menu(array(
        'theme-location' => 'primary',
        'container_class' => 'primary-nav-container',
        'menu_class' => 'primary-nav',
    ));
    echo '</nav>';
}
add_action('ao-primary-nav', 'ao_primary_nav');
```

Then after that, you should be able to add the following to replace all of the code that you showed from header.php with this:

```
do_action('ao-primary-nav');
```

**Warning:** Doing this will destroy the styles attached to your theme's navigation. So don't erase the code the is already there, but instead simply use this to check to see if the navigation functionality is still existent. From here we can see if the theme overall is outdated or if there are bigger underlying issues. **This is not a permanent solution. However, if this works and you see A NAVIGATION then it is a good sign that we can dig into the theme further to see what exactly is going on.**

You could also always check the changelog of the theme to see when it was last updated and that could be a good sign of whether or not you should use it.

Answer (score 0):

Menu is working fine in Hotheme. You have to read the documentation provided in http://www.hotheme.co/page-documentation.php#doc-3-1. In Menu topic they have mentioned, name the menu as "**default**".